# why github pages not rendering my site, React

Tags: reactjs, deployment, github-pages

I have created a site with react, redux, and firebase as a backend and pushed it to git but when I'm tired to create a GitHub page to the site it builds Succesful and uploaded the files to the gh-pages, but when I'm entring the link it doesn't render the site

my repo : https://github.com/alon4551/Crown-Market

my site : https://alon4551.github.io/Crown-Market/

I've also installed the gh-pages in my project and add this lines in my package json
and runed the command `npm run deploy`

```
"homepage": "https://github.io/alon4551/Crown-Market",
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"}
```

can someone help me

Answer (score 0):

The home page should be set up this way:

```
"homepage": "https://myusername.github.io/my-app"
```

for a more detailed explanation, [Create-React-App Deployment Guide](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#step-1-add-homepage-to-packagejson)